# NodeJS - Visual Studio 2019-app.js exited with code -1

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2019

I am new to NodeJs.I begin NodeJs by using Visual Studio 2019 as IDE.When i run the project I endup with message showing that 
The program 'app.js' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

How to fix it?